# ffmpeg: How do I select a random frame every second?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a video with variable FPS that I want to reduce to 1 FPS. Additionally I want this one frame per second to be randomly sampled within the second. So let's assume a video of 5FPS, 3 seconds long, the frame indexes are:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[0 ... 4] is the 1st second
[5 ... 9] is the 2nd second
[10 ... 14] is the 3rd second
```

I'd like one frame between `[0 ... 4]`, one frame for `[5 ... 9]` and one frame between `[10 ... 14]`.

What I have tried so far is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter:v "select='random(1)',fps=1" -f mp4 output.mp4
```

However this is always sampling the frames in perfect 1 second intervals. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This basically does the job, however the PRNG output can be improved.

`-filter:v "select='st(1,mod(t\,floor(t)));if(eq(n\,0),1,(floor(t)-floor(prev_selected_t))*gt(ld(1)\,random(7)))',setpts=N,fps=1"`

Comment: Thank you so much, Gyan! I think I understand your answer. The logic is as following: if it's the first frame, select it. Otherwise: `(floor(t) - floor(prev_selected_t))*((t % floor(t)) > random(7))`. The first part of the expression, before the *, is checking if a frame was already selected for that second interval. The second part is a trick to select a random frame. (Note: It doesn't guarantee that a frame will be selected for that interval due to random(7) being different for every frame).

Comment: How can I set the seed used by `random(7)`? I tried adding `st(7, <seed as an INT>)` to the beginning but it seems like the same frames are sampled regardless of what seed I set.